# Image button Custom Control, silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am trying to build the Image button by setting

```
<Button.Content>
<Image Source="..."/>
</Button.Content>
```

Everything is Fine but i am not able to set the Visual States when button is clicked i wanted to something like Flash on top of button (Blue Purple Theme).

One more thing I need to create around 10 such button with different Images I think Custom Control works fine.

Any help is appretiated.

Thanks 
Lavanya

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to re-template your Button(s) and wrap that up into a Style.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-7-using-control-templates-to-customize-a-control-s-look-and-feel.aspx

Then use the VisualStateManager (easiest from within Blend 3) to change the visual properties on various states.

http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/stylestemplatesvsm-cs/